# how to create a specific date format in php

Tags: php

We have a current date format is `02-05-15` and the output that I want is `02/05/2015` in PHP.

Comment: You have to try first

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', "02-05-15");
echo  $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y');
// Output : 02/05/2015
```

---

**Note:**

You may also want to set the default timezone before using `DateTime`, i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
```

---

For `date_and_time` and other php best practices visit:

http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way

```
$sections      = explode('-','02-05-15');
$formated_date = $sections[0]."/".$sections[1]."/20".$sections[2];
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
<?php
   $time = mktime(0,0,0, '02', '05', '15'); 
   //OR mktime(0,0,0, '05', '02', '15'); //depending on the expected format
   echo date("d/m/Y",$time); //assuming the above date is 2 May 2015
   //alternatively it would be
   echo date('m/d/Y', $time); //if the above date is 5 February 2015
?>
```

Comment: This outputs 15/05/2002 .

Comment: Thanks @PedroLobito, Updated the code

Comment: I guess you'll have to try harder...`date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in /home/cg/root/main.php on line 3`

Comment: Again, thanks @PedroLobito, bug fixed

Comment: Do you actually test your code? it doesn't seem so! now it returns `01/01/1970` you can test it online... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php

Comment: Link wasn't working earlier on so I had to do it locally and yeah, fixed it up as shown.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

> $date = "02-05-15";
>  $format_date = date('m/d/Y',
>   strtotime($date));

For more details about formats, please refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)